# What is the best or proposed way to feed keyframed/animated parameters into Blender script?

Tags: python, animation, scripting, keyframes

In order to feed some animated parameters into a Blender application (meaning a more or less complex script) I'm actually miss-using simple Input-Value nodes in the compositor.
There I can set the desired keyframe-values and Blender animates them accordingly. From within the script I can grab the current value in the frame-change handler and process them further.

This method is working just fine but I'm wondering whether this is the intended method of doing such things?
Of course, one method is to implement all this keyframing and animation of these parameters inside the script. For a few cases I even did this. But it is not very convenient.

On top of that there is an issue in conjunction with the "Lock Interface" option during rendering an animation. I did not yet sort this out completely, but I often get crashes of Blender during rendering an animation, which is probably associated with multithreading-issues that can be probably avoided by using to "Lock Interface" option. However, when I use that option the animation of the keyframable Input-Value nodes is not working any more. I'm not sure whether this is a bug or a feature resp. the nature of this locking mechanism. At least the script cannot read the proper values any more. So when there is some other method this problem might disappear as well.

Thanks for any hints,
Mario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to input values, you can make UI panels. You can define and save properties for many things in Blender like objects, materials, scenes and so on and you can read them with your script:

```
import bpy

bpy.types.WindowManager.int_prop = bpy.props.IntProperty(name = "Integer", default=15)
bpy.types.WindowManager.float_prop = bpy.props.FloatProperty(name = "Float", default=3.141592)
bpy.types.WindowManager.string_prop = bpy.props.StringProperty(name = "String", default="dsfsdvcx")
bpy.types.WindowManager.bool_prop = bpy.props.BoolProperty(name = "Boolean", default=False)
bpy.types.WindowManager.enum_prop = bpy.props.EnumProperty(
            #(identifier, name, description, icon, number)
    items = [('a','a','','',0), 
             ('b','b','','',1),
             ('c','c','','',2),
             ('d','d','','',4)],
    name = "Enum",
    default = 'a')

class LayoutDemoPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the scene context of the properties editor"""
    bl_label = "Layout Demo"
    bl_idname = "SCENE_PT_layout"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "scene"
    
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        col = layout.column()
        col.prop(context.window_manager, "int_prop")
        col.prop(context.window_manager, "float_prop")
        col.prop(context.window_manager, "string_prop")
        col.prop(context.window_manager, "bool_prop")
        col.prop(context.window_manager, "enum_prop")

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(LayoutDemoPanel)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(LayoutDemoPanel)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

See this: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html also have a look at Python templates in the text editor's Templates menu:

[image]

You can create panels pretty much in every corner of Blender's UI wherever it's appropriate for your purpose.

It's also quite easy to make custom properties:

[image]

That would be `bpy.data.objects['Suzanne']['prop']` it's not only for objects - lot's of thing can have those.

Operators can have their properties that are available in Repeat Last Operator panel, so you can write operators that can take input from there. See Operator templates in the Text Editor's Templates menu.

So those are a few ways, but you can take input from pretty much anywhere. It's Python - whatever you can do with Python, you can do it here.

Comment: Thanks @Martynas Žiemys! I did use the custom properties that I did add to the scene. It's working perfectly. It is also overcoming this issue when "Lock Interface" is active - meaning that the parameters are animated properly as well. So I hope that now I can leave the system working unattended for hours and days without crashes....